# If f is a linear function of one variable,then how many points on the graph of the function are needed to specify the function?

Tags: linear-algebra

If f is a linear function of one variable,then how many points on the graph of the function are needed to specify the function?Give an explicit expression for f in terms of these points.

I believe one variable needs 2 points

F(x) = b
F(x) = a

Or x = {a, b}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this looks like homework, let me just point out that you may misunderstand what a linear function is. The answer will depend on the dimension of the preimage domain of $f$ and can be as low as 1, in particular if $f$ just takes a real value.

EDIT: You asked for a little more detail.

$f$ is a linear function, so it takes values from one vector space, which we'll name $X$, and produces values in some (not necessarily different) vector space, which we'll name $Y$. $X$ is called the *preimage* of $f$, and the values in $Y$ which $f$ does take for some input are called the $image$ of $f$. (That doesn't have to be all of $Y$. For example, the constant function $f\equiv 0$ is a linear function. Note that $f\equiv 1$ is *not*.)

Now, if you know that, e.g., for $x=\left({1\atop 0}\right)$, $f\!\left(\left({1\atop 0}\right)\right)=\left({2\atop0}\right)$, then you can deduce what $f\!\left(\left({2\atop 0}\right)\right)$ must be, but you don't know anything about $f\!\left(\left({1\atop 1}\right)\right)$. So if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^2$, we know one value cannot be enough.

Comment: Words like dimension and preimage are outside the scope of the chapter on Vector Spaces. Can you try to explain it again?

Comment: “Dimension” is outside the scope of the chapter on vector spaces? What exactly does that chapter talk about then, if it never gets around to vector spaces having bases? But I'll put a little more meat into the answer, all right.

Comment: It goes into basis actually, very very lightly. It gets into more detail in a future chapter they promise @christophercreutzing

Comment: just so I understand, "one variable" means one input,x, right? Why does your example have 2 inputs, x, and y?

Comment: No, that is one input. That is just how you deal with vector spaces: An element of the vector space is one value. (A vector can need infinitely many real numbers to be determined, so it doesn't make sense to always talk about those.)